# Evince print to pdf file fails to print

Tags: 11.04, pdf, printing, evince

This is my problem:

- Open a document in Evince, choose Print
- Choose "Printer": "Print to file"
- Choose "Output Format": "PDF"
- (add a filename output.pdf in the box if not there)
- Click on "Print"
- Experience the following message:

...

```
Failed to print document.
Printing is not supported on this printer.
```

By the way, printing to an "Output Format" .ps file works fine.

What am I missing?

Comment: Is only one specific pdf document or are all pdf documents affected? We can't reproduce this error message here.

Comment: Hi @Takkat - thanks for responding! I think the original file was a PostScript .ps generate from the Plot command in `kicad`... I have just tried a little test, and it seems that if the original file is PDF, then "Print to File" to PDF will work.. Apparently, this is some strange postscript here... If I get some time later, I'll try to do a more proper test case.

Answer (score 2):

Not by any means a satisfactory answer, but I can reproduce this problem exactly so I opened a bug for it,

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evince/+bug/784228

You might want to subscribe to it.

Comment: Thanks for that, @Olivier - I have copied the Launchpad bug to Gnome's Bugzilla: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=650461 ... Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

probably not the best answer, but one workaround might be to process it in gimp batch mode.  it supports importing postscript and exporting pdf(it will just be a page sized image with no character notation though).  just one possible workaround.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @aking1012 - had no idea `gimp` was capable of this; I'd have to try it out! Cheers!